# Small batch size brewing trub issues

Tags: small-batch, trub, techniques

Five gallon batches generate a certain amount of trub in the fermenter.  However, its a relatively small percent of the total batch.  I am interested in trying some 2 gallon maybe even one gallon batch sizes for kicks.

I wonder if there is a batch size point at which the trub to beer ratio becomes to big to get a decent amount of beer from.  Obviously the trub amount will decrease as the batch size goes down, but is it really linear.

Anyone ever tried a one gallon batch (in an appropriately sized fermenter)?

Comment: Great question, I have been thinking about doing some some one gallon batches just to see what would be best for a recipe, like a porter.  I could have a chocolate, a coffee, a chocolate coffee.  And I could use the individual gallons to test the amount of chocolate or coffee to add, without brewing five different batches I could just split my five gallons into five one gallon batches.  If no one answers this before I try it, I'll let you know how it looks as far as trub is concerned.

Comment: I brewed a one gallon recipe last night and it's sitting in a homemade 6-8 quart plastic primary fermenter. I'll update on trub levels once fermentation is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do 2 gallon batches on occasion.  The brew-in-a-bag method is great for this, but you get *a lot* of trub.  In this 1-gallon jug the dark band under the krausen ring is beer, the rest is suspended stuff.  After a few weeks it all settled and I got six bottles of nice looking (and tasting) beer.

[image: Trub]

Comment: Only 6 beers out of 2 gallons!!!  I'd expect more than that out of 1 gallon.  do you filer your work prior to pouring??